# Why is that GIFs background color grey instead of white/transparent?

Tags: html, css, button

I am using that gif image from PayPal

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif

On PayPal's website, the area around that button appears as white/transparent.

When I use that same image as a `background-image` in CSS, for my own button "Buy now", the area is grey around it.

http://jsfiddle.net/gGeBp/1/

Why is that? I am using Safari.

Comment: seems to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gGeBp/

Comment: Hi, I updated your jsfiddle. Im actually trying to use it as a button
http://jsfiddle.net/gGeBp/1/

Comment: is your background-color grey?

Comment: add background-color:white or whatever; the default bg color for button likely is that grey...

Comment: oh thanks a lot for that. You can put it up as an answer. Regards

Comment: It's a problem of the input button... you have to put the backgroundcolor to white/transparent, then it will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `background-color:transparent`:

```
#buynow_button {
   background-color: transparent;
   ...
}
```